# Need Java Based Report Writing Package To Incorporate Into Java Application

Tags: java, report

I have a java based application that includes a report generation capability.   The report module retrieves information from a back - end database formats the data, then displays it in a window from which it can be printed.   The capabilities of this module are rudimentary.   I would like to incorporate a more sophisticated report generation tool.    Does such a package exists?  I want to incorporate calls to this functionality into my application.   The package of functions can either be open source or commercial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Birt](http://eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) or [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports).

I'm not totally sure on Birt as I don't have to book at home and haven't done it yet. However you can programatically generate reports with Jasper Reports.

Both support generating a report from a template you designed with a report designer. Birt is probably more powerful then the open source jasper reports. Both have a commercial counter-part.

Answer (score 0):

Also, Crystal now has a java tool, but I understand from people that used it that it has some issues as well.